# Deleting python3.6 makes Ubuntu budgie 18.10 unable to boot up

Tags: ubuntu, python3

I just downloaded `python3.7` and I wanted to delete the old version `python3.6`, so I did

```
sudo apt remove pyhton3.6
```

And a lot of stuff was deleted. Next, after a shutdown of the computer, it came back to it, it doesn't boot up anymore. It is stuck at the loading screen of Ubuntu.

I tried rebooting several times, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Python is pretty deeply integrated into Ubuntu. Not saying that this can't be fixed, but it may take some effort.